# Can we count an uncountable noun to mean that it is a type of something

Tags: uncountable-nouns

Can we count an uncountable noun (or an usually uncountable noun) to mean that it is a type of something?

Examples:

> 1
>   This thing is a food. (to mean that this is a type of food.)
>
> 2
>   This thing is an air. (to mean that this a type of air.)
>
> 3
>   This thing is a water. (to mean that this a type of water.)

Comment: This kind of usage works with ***food***, because everyone knows there are many different types of food, so it's quite reasonable to identify "this thing" as one of them (but we'd often say something is a ***foodstuff*** to make the intended sense more obvious). But things like ***air, water*** are already thought of as specific types of ***gas, liquid*** - most people would have trouble understanding what you meant by "type of water", because for most purposes *all* water is just "water".

Comment: Even with 'food' it would sound like pretty poor English to me. 'This thing is food' would make sense though.

Comment: In that context, yes, @JacobLee-Hart. But what about _This is a food that I like_?

Answer (score -1):

No, all your initial sentences are incorrect, you have to use 'a type of' in front of it.

> This thing is a type of food
>
> This thing is a type of air
>
> This thing is a type of water

You can never use an indefinite article (a/an) in front of uncountable nouns.

Comment: I have seen plenty of references to mass nouns using an indefinite article in British English, the 'type of' being implicit- e.g. "In the case of a coal from South Wales, the dull layers give a composition of: Moisture, 1-68; volatile matter, 14.71; fixed carbonaceous residue, 77-17; ash, 644"  "Coal in Great Britain" (1920). Also I can think of 'porter is a beer', 'roses do not like an alkaline soil'.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. The OP was asking about a real, though complex, feature of English, and you are replying JLH by denying that the feature exists.

Comment: What seemed to run through his veins was a blood so pure, so fine, that it hardly seemed possible that he could vote for the Conservatives. Yes. He was a charlatan.

Comment: I daresay we all know what, according to Rupert Brooke, is buried in a corner of a foreign field (in that rich earth a richer dust concealed) ?